# How can i display the categories to which a post belongs to as selected and also all categories

Tags: php, laravel, blogs

Hope you all are doing great. I have a many to many relationship between posts and categories table. By using the pivot table i am able to get all the categories to which a post belongs to but i am unable to get all the categories present in the database.

This is my edit post method:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $post=Post::find($post->id);
    $categories=Category::all();
    return view('admin.pages.post.edit',compact('post','categories'));
}
```

This is what im using in my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Categories</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="select2" name="categories_id[]" multiple="multiple">
     @foreach($post->categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" selected>{{ $category->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
```

^^ This shows the current category/categories to which the post belongs to.

Right now i have a post that belongs to WEB category. And it is showing WEB as a category in the edit page But i also want to display all the categories(AI,ML etc) to which the post originally doesnot belong to so that a user has the choice to update the categories to which the post belongs to.

Also i am using select2 as the multiple select box

This is what i have 
[image]

This is what im after
[image]

Comment: Highly recommend LaravelCollective - form model binding can automatically take care of this.  For now, you are setting "selected" on everything - do an if-check to see if you should set the selected flag.

Comment: That is the problem as i cant seem to figure out the logic to set only the categories to which a post belongs to as selected. My pivot table has two columns cat_id and post_id

Comment: I am a newbie in laravel and started off by developing a small blog on my own to learn it. As of now i have learned mare laravel by this blog then i could ever by following the tutorials

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML form, you can do a check to see if the `id` is part of the `$post` like this (I'll do the easiest to understand, you can refactor in a number of ways):

```
 <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{isset($post->categories->where('id', $category->id)->first())?'selected':''}}>{{ $category->name}}</option>
```

To make this easy and with fewest calls to the database, load the categories relationship onto your posts before the loop on the blade view.  You don't need the line you have (`$post=Post::find($post->id);`) because your route-model binding has already injected it.

In your **Controller**'s `edit` method:

```
 public function edit(Post $post)
 {
     $post->load('categories');
     $categories=Category::all();
     return view('admin.pages.post.edit',compact('post','categories'));
 }
```

I assume you have the relationship from `categories` to `posts` set up correctly in your **Post** model.  But this is essentially just asking 'if this post on this form has THIS category (per this loop), then mark it selected'.

I really love the LaravelCollective way to do this, and also recommend you take a look [at the library](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html).  It binds the model to the form, and automatically picks the selected item for you.  You could do it in a simple line like this with the Collective:

```
 {!! Form::select('categories[]', $categories, null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple', 'id'=>'categories']) !!}
```

Comment: OK, I've edited - you will need to load your `posts` with `categories`. I've also changed the `exists()` to `first() `+ `isset` to make it more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the issue after hours of searching

In the edit method i did :

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $post=Post::with('tags','categories')->find($post->id);
    $tags=Tag::all();
    $categories=Category::all();
    return view('admin.pages.post.edit',compact('post','categories','tags'));
}
```

In the view i did:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label>Categories</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="categories" name="categories[]" multiple="multiple">
           @foreach($categories as $category)
           <option value="{{ $category->id }}"
                @foreach($post->categories as $postCat)
                      {{ $postCat->id==$category->id?'Selected':'' }}
                @endforeach
           >{{ $category->name}}</option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
```